# Поиск столбца в таблице бд sql php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Как проверить есть ли столбец `name` в `sql` таблице `users` с помощью pdo php?
Перед создание столбца в таблице нужно проверить есть ли столбец с таким же названием.

Comment: вы лучше свою задачу опишите, а то получите костыль. И укажите СУБД. Ибо адекватный вариант - написать запрос к схеме данных и выбрать столбцы. А костыльный - извлечь одну строку `select * `из таблицы с FETCH_ASSOC, и вывести ключи полученного массива

Comment: @teran описал в описании вопроса

Comment: СУБД забыли указать. mysql, sqlserver, postgre, oracle. добавьте соответствующую метку в вопрос

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24571611/mysql-alter-table-if-column-not-exists

Comment: @teran мне нужно на уровне php проверить есть ли столбец с таким названием, если есть менять названия нового столбца для его создания.

Comment: Пробуете что-то записать - если исключение - значит, столбец есть, а нет исключения - то создавать.

Comment: дак я вам вроде как привел ссылку на запросы, которые определяют есть ли столбец. в чем проблема выполнить их  в пхп?

Answer (score 0):

```
 public function addColumn(string $tableName, string $columnName): void
    {
    try {
    // подключаемся к серверу
    $conn = $this->pdo;
    // проверка на существование столбца
    $selectSql = "SELECT 1 FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE 
    TABLE_SCHEMA = '{$this->db}' AND TABLE_NAME = '{$tableName}' 
    AND COLUMN_NAME = '{$columnName}'";
    $sth = $conn->query($selectSql);
    $result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if (!$result) {
    // SQL-выражение для создания столбца
    $addColumnSql = "ALTER TABLE $tableName 
    ADD $columnName SMALLINT UNSIGNED NULL";
    // выполняем SQL-выражение
    $conn->exec($addColumnSql);
    echo "Столбец пользователя добавлен";
    }
    } catch (Throwable $e) {
    echo "Ошибка базы данных: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
    }
```